# Why do games have different ports for different maps?

Tags: networking

A little old example for that would be Metin2, this is the only game I know which have that, but there may be more.
In Metin2 there are maps which are accessable through other ports. 
I'm not a network specialist, but I think then it is needed to connect to an other port on an map change.

So would it not be possible todo all that on one port? Are there any benefits from that?

Could it be that there is a limit on port connections on a server, that this would be something for loadbalancing?

Comment: What kind of game are YOU making? What problem are YOU trying to solve?

Comment: Do I actually need to develop a game, to ask questions on gamedev? I'm currently researched a bit cause I actually want to make a game, then this question came in my mind.

Comment: Questions about "how or why other games do <some thing>" aren't generally on-topic here, so yes, having a specific problem helps scope that. If you just want to have a discussion about how or why this might work in general as a best practice, you may want to ask on [GDNet](http://www.gamedev.net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Massive multiplayer online games like Metin2 are often too large to be handled by just a single server. A common solution is to have multiple servers and have each server handle a different region of the game world. Usually every server needs their own IP address. But static IP addresses are not free. Every IP you need usually costs extra. A possible workaround is to assign one IP address to a router and have it route each port to a different server on the local area network behind it.